# Bottle Websockets Example That Updates Every Few Seconds

Tags: python, jquery, websocket, bottle, gevent

As I'm trying to understand websockets with a minimum of javascript knowledge I'm running into major holes in my understanding. A clean example seems like
[Bottle websockets example](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html)

and the websockets server and client example there work for me. But I wanted to for example have the time update every 10 seconds on the HTML client. So I just did in the server.

```
while True:
    wsock.send("Time: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    time.sleep(10)
```

The time shows once but never updates. Trying to do this for a Raspberry Pi project I came across a nodejs example which update sensor values; in this eample there's some Jquery code which I thought I could adapt to the HTML file code in the Bottle example...They are using Jquery .data to "hook into" a table element perhaps that updates.
[NodeJS Updating weosockets example](http://www.bonebrews.com/ds18b20-temperatures-in-your-browser/)

But I can't make the leap to adapt that Jquery "pattern" to Bottle. If someone had the time for just a snippet perhaps it would become obvious. Thanks.

Comment: We need more code to help I suspect.  I use websockets in my apps, and it's relatively straight forward.  If you offered your code, I could help more.

Answer (score 0):

People tend to overcomplicate websockets.  I love Gevent because it makes it super easy to implement.  There are a few caveats however.  if you combine websockets with your current WSGI app, you get blocking on the individual connection when it waits to recieve, so add a timeout.

Here is an example running under Gevent Websockets.  This makes it ASYNC  and allows for bidirectional communication.

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, signal, Timeout, sleep, spawn as gspawn
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketError
import bottle
from bottle import get, route, template, request, response, abort, static_file
import ujson as json

@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='static')

@route('/ws/remote')
def handle_websocket():
    message = 'TEST'
    wsock = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not wsock:
        abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')
    while 1:
        wsock.send(message) # example of how to send data
        sleep(10) #pause this thread only for 10 seconds
        try:
            with Timeout(2, False) as timeout: #if you want to receive
                message = wsock.receive()
            if message:
                message = json.loads(message)
                if 'command' in message:
                    r.command(message['command'])
        except WebSocketError:
            break
        except Exception as exc:
            print(str(exc))


@get('/')
def remote():
    return template('templates/remote.tpl', title='WebsocketTest', websocket=WEBSOCKET, command='command', status=status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    r=None
    status="Connecting..."
    gspawn(initialize)
    print 'Started...'
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    HOST = 'localhost'
    WEBSOCKET =  'ws://{}/ws/remote'.format(HOST)
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 80), botapp, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown) #CTRL C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Then in your HTML you really should use reconnecting websocket library
https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket

```
<button id="TRIGGERED" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">TRIGGER</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/reconnecting-websocket.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ws = new ReconnectingWebSocket('{{websocket}}');
ws.reconnectInterval = 3000;
ws.maxReconnectAttempts = 10;

ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var wsmsg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    console.log(evt.data)
    };


$("button").click(function() {
    <!--console.log(this.id);-->
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({'{{command}}': this.id}));
});
</script>
```